# how to move up row to find the last or first occurrence of the same number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table name **current_record** in mysql database.

```
   id         num
   1          0
   2          1
   3          1 
   4          1
   5          0
```

my question is : how find the 1st id of num = 1 from last means down to up or 3 times up
the output should return like this

```
  id = 2 num = 1
```

please write a sql query.

Comment: Just a `MIN(id) WHERE num = 1`?

Comment: Your question _“how find the 1st id of num = 1 from last means down to up or 3 times up the output should return like this”_ makes almost no sense. Please punctuate it so that we can understand it.

Comment: You should show your attempt and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` combined with `GROUP BY` to achieve this.  Something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, num FROM current_record GROUP BY num
```

Optionally you can add a `WHERE` clause if you specifically want just one value instead of one for each `num`:

```
WHERE num == 1
```